# Caulking Vertical Seams in Three Piece Shower/Bathtub

Tags: plumbing

I recently purchased a condo and the upstairs bathroom has a shower/bathtub with three interlocking pieces making up the shower wall.  After some research it is unclear if I should caulk these vertical seams.  Some responses suggest that every seam in a shower should be caulked while others suggest that these types of shower wall seams are left un-caulked for a reason.  Is there any consensus on this?  Thank you.

Here is a picture of the seam:

[image: shower seam]

Here is a picture of how the pieces are joined together:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be a subjective question. Here's how I'd approach it.

1. Read the installation manual. It's often spelled out clearly which seams should be caulked and which should (or must) remain uncaulked. Sometimes caulking the wrong place results in leaks or overflow.
2. Consider the problem of trapped moisture and mold/mildew. If caulking a seam would result in puddling or extended moisture accumulation, and doens't resolve a drainage problem, it may be worth avoiding.
3. Does the caulk joint improve or degrade the aesthetics of the unit? Well-done caulk joints virtually disappear into the structure. Poor ones look amateurish and messy. Can the joint be done well in a given location?

If you decide to caulk a joint, I recommend 100% silicone. Latex-based caulks collect surface soil, shrink considerably, and may not bond as well to non-porous surfaces. Be sure the surface is very clean beforehand.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately this bath tub came already installed with the condo.  Your general guidelines are very helpful though.

Comment: Manuals are often available with a little searching. You have a brand name, right?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the brand name.  I did add pictures if that will help at all.